# Prevent html entity conversion php

Tags: php, html, url

I have a form with a url input that I need to prevent from converting, so that I can use $_GET on the target page. I have tried urlencode, urldecode, html_entity_decode, etc, but none of it prevents the html entity conversion (parse_url did nothing but get rid of all the important stuff).  [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/ZzFCmuJIZGE) is the only thread I have found that comes close to what I am trying to achieve.

It seems like there should be a simple solution, and this is not happening anywhere else I am using a url like this...

Thanks to anyone who can help!

```
echo "<option value='seeArtist.php?aid=".$row[0]."&ac=".$row[1]."&img=".$row[2]."'">
(blah, blah)
<input type="submit" style="margin-left:10px" name="submit" value="Go" />';
```

This is the result from clicking the submit button.

```
seeArtist.php?art_con=seeArtist.php%3Faid%3D18%26not%3Bac%3D+(aka)+Banksy%26not%3Bimg%3D0&submit=Go
```

Two variables are integers, so the database content is not url-encoded.

I suspect that since this is not happening anywhere else, and this is the only place where I am putting a link in a select option, that it has something to do with the submit action. In firebug the link shows up exactly the way it is supposed to. When I submit the url gets encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the PHP, your HTML is incorrect. You need to encode the ampersands. Your code should resemble this:

```
echo "<option value=\"seeArtist.php?aid=" . $row[0] . "&amp;ac=" . $row[1] . "&amp;img=" . $row[2] . "\">\r\n";
```

I also took the liberty of converting single-quotes to escaped double-quotes.

Comment: This is the result from your code. Is this happening after the page is reached? The same thing happens with my code. seeArtist.php?art_con=seeArtist.php%3Faid%3D18%26ac%3D+Banksy%26img%3D0&submit=Go

Comment: @artsyL Please repost that into your question (by showing us the **rendered** HTML, not what the browser displays). Furthermore, it looks like your database content is already URL-encoded. We need more information. A screenshot of data in your database would help too.

Comment: Thanks. I added more info.